# Arrays Inside Objects: Conditional Updating Of One Object's Array From Another Object's Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, filter

**DISCLAIMER**

I have absolutely no idea how to succinctly describe the nature of the problem I am trying to solve without going deep into context. It took me forever to even think of an appropriate title. For this reason I've found it nearly impossible to find an answer both on here and the web at large that will assist me. It's possible my question can be distilled down into something simple which does already have an answer on here. If this is the case I apologise for the elaborate duplicate

**TL;DR**

I have two arrays: a main array `members` and a destination array `neighbours` (technically many destination arrays but this is the tl;dr). The main array is a property of my custom group object which is auto-populated with custom ball objects. The destination array is a property of my custom ball object. I need to scan each element inside of the `members` array and calculate distance between that element and every other element in the `members` group. If there exist other elements within a set distance of the current element then these other elements need to be copied into the current element's destination array. This detection needs to happen in realtime. When two elements become close enough to be neighbours they are added to their respective `neighbours` array. The moment they become too far apart to be considered neighbours they need to be removed from their respective `neighbours` array.

**CONTEXT**

My question is primarily regarding array iteration, comparison and manipulation but to understand my exact dilemma I need to provide some context. My contextual code snippets have been made as brief as possible. I am using the Phaser library for my project, but my question is not Phaser-dependent.

I have made my own object called Ball. The object code is:

```
Ball = function Ball(x, y, r, id) {
  this.position = new Vector(x, y); //pseudocode Phaser replacement
  this.size = r;
  this.id = id;
  this.PERCEPTION = 100;
  this.neighbours = []; //the destination array this question is about
}
```

All of my Ball objects (so far) reside in a group. I have created a `BallGroup` object to place them in. The relevant `BallGroup` code is:

```
BallGroup = function BallGroup(n) { //create n amount of Balls
  this.members = []; //the main array I need to iterate over

  /*fill the array with n amount of balls upon group creation*/
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    /*code for x, y, r, id generation not included for brevity*/
    this.members.push(new Ball(_x, _y, _r, _i)
  }

}
```

I can create a group of 4 Ball objects with the following:

```
group = new BallGroup(4);
```

This works well and with the Phaser code I haven't included I can click/drag/move each Ball. I also have some `Phaser.utils.debug.text(...)` code which displays the distance between each Ball in an easy to read 4x4 table (with duplicates of course as distance Ball0->Ball3 is the same as distance Ball3->Ball0). For the text overlay I calculate the distance with a nested `for` loop:

```
for (a = 0; a < group.members.length; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < group.members.length; b++) {
        distance = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(group.members[a].x - group.members[b].x), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(group.members[a].y - group.members[b].y), 2)));
        //Phaser text code
    }
}
```

**Now to the core of my problem.** Each Ball has a range of detection `PERCEPTION = 100`. I need to iterate over every `group.members` element and calculate the distance between that element (`group.members[a]`) and every other element within the `group.members` array (this calculation I can do). The problem I have is I cannot then copy those elements whose distance to `group.members[a]` is < `PERCEPTION` into the `group.members[a].neighbours` array.

The reason I have my main array (`BallGroup.members`) inside one object and my destination array inside a different object (`Ball.neighbours`) is because I need each Ball within a BallGroup to be aware of it's own neighbours without caring for what the neighbours are for every other Ball within the BallGroup. However, I believe that the fact these two arrays (main and destination) are within different objects is why I am having so much difficulty.

**But there is a catch**. This detection needs to happen in realtime and when two Balls are no longer within the `PERCEPTION` range they must then be removed from their respective `neighbours` array.

**EXAMPLE**

```
group.members[0] -> no neighbours
group.members[1] -> in range of [2] and [3]
group.members[2] -> in range of [1] only
group.members[3] -> in range of [1] only

//I would then expect group.members[1].neighbours to be an array with two entries, 
//and both group.members[2].neighbours and group.members[3].neighbours to each 
//have the one entry. group.members[0].neighbours would be empty
```

I drag group.members[2] and group.members[3] away to a corner by themselves

```
group.members[0] -> no neighbours
group.members[1] -> no neighbours
group.members[2] -> in range of [3] only
group.members[3] -> in range of [2] only

//I would then expect group.members[2].neighbours and group.members[3].neighbours 
//to be arrays with one entry. group.members[1] would change to have zero entries
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I've tried enough things to confuse any person, which is why I'm coming here for help. I first tried complex nested `for` loops and `if/else` statements. This resulted in neighbours being infinitely added and started to become too complex for me to keep track of.

I looked into `Array.forEach` and `Array.filter`. I couldn't figure out if `forEach` could be used for what I needed and I got very excited learning about what `filter` does (return an array of elements that match a condition). When using `Array.filter` it either gives the Ball object zero neighbours or includes every other Ball as a neighbour regardless of distance (I can't figure out why it does what it does, but it definitely isn't what I need it to do). At the time of writing this question my current code for detecting neighbours is this:

```
BallGroup = function BallGroup(n) {
    this.members = []; //the main array I need to iterate over

    //other BallGroup code here

    this.step = function step() {                         //this function will run once per frame
        for (a = 0; a < this.members.length; a++) {       //members[a] to be current element
            for (b = 0; b < this.members.length; b++) {   //members[b] to be all other elements
                if (a != b) {                             //make sure the same element isn't being compared against itself
                    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(this.members[a].x - this.members[b].x), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(this.members[a].y - this.members[b].y), 2));
                    function getNeighbour(element, index, array) {
                        if (distance < element.PERCEPTION) {
                           return true;
                        }
                    }
                    this.members[a].neighbours = this.members.filter(getNeighbour);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope my problem makes sense and is explained well enough. I know exactly what I need to do in the context of my own project, but putting that into words for others to understand who have no idea about my project has been a challenge. I'm learning Javascript as I go and have been doing great so far, but this particular situation has me utterly lost. I'm in too deep, but I don't want to give up - I want to learn!

Many, many, many thanks for those who took the time read my very long post and tried provide some insight.

*edit: changed a > to a <*

Answer (score 1):

I was learning more on object literals, I'm trying to learn JS to ween myself off of my jQuery dependency. I'm making a simple library and I made a function that adds properties of one object to another object. It's untested, but I think if you were apply something similar it might help. I'll try to find my resources. Btw, I don't have the articles on hand right now, but I recall that using new could incur complications, sorry I can't go any further than that, I'll post more info as I find it.

1. xObject could be the ball group
2. Obj2 could be the members
3. Obj1 could be the destination

```js
/* augment(Obj1, Obj2) |  Adds properties of Obj2 to Obj1. */

// xObject has augment() as a method called aug

var xObject = {
  aug: augument
}

/* Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) */

(function() {

  var Obj1 = {},

    Obj2 = {
      bool: true,
      num: 3,
      str: "text"
    }

  xObject.aug(Obj1, Obj2);

}()); // invoke immediately

function augment(Obj1, Obj2) {

  var prop;

  for (prop in Obj2) {

    if (Obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !Obj1[prop]) {

      Obj1[prop] = Obj2[prop];
    }
  }
}
```